# How do I reference the choice values in a Datastore model in a Jinja2 create.HTML template in GAE-Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [choice property in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845685/choice-property-in-google-app-engine)

I am a newbie to App Engine and also to Python (my experience is with ASP).

The DataModeling section of AppEngine Documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling) provides an example that starts as:

```
class Pet(db.Model):  
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    type = db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=set(["cat", "dog", "bird"]), default="dog")
```

How do I reference these allowable values in a Jinja2 PetCreate.html template?

I am not sure if the choices option is only a Django-related structure (I am not using Django - only Jinja2)

It seems it would not make sense to have to hard-code these values into a html select structure (why bother putting it in the model if I have to hard code the allowable values in every create and edit case anyway).

Can anyone give me an example of what the PetCreate.html template might look like to go with this model?

I am using Python2.7 and trying to use Jinja2 for templates and want to stay with Datastore (not Cloud SQL).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up not needing this because I decided I wanted to hard code the forms for other reasons.  Having said that, I saw references of this using NDB, jinja2 and WTForms.